# Dynamic continuous form height

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a form that has a continuous subform in the footer to show "comments" for the original form record.

My issue is that each comment is of an undetermined size. I am trying to find a way to dynamically change the height of each section in the continuous form to match its contents.

Reading around online I found a lot of people saying this couldn't be done (a few years ago, so whether this is still the case I am not sure) so I tried instead to layout my own "continuous form" in the form header of the subform. This involved creating a text box for each comment using the [CreateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221167%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method. Unfortunately this method didn't work either, the new controls completely failed to appear on the form at runtime.

I am sure there is some way this can be done (maybe an alternative method to achieve the same effect) but I can't seem to find it.

Anyone had experienced with this problem or any ideas on how else I may achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Each record in the subform will always be the same height (the Detail section height). What I've done in the past is to make it fairly small but add a button (or use the Click event of the text box) to open the Zoom box with the whole commment.